How to use ave() and seq_along() functions in R to make a column with a previous date for a group
I am beginner with R and try to combine the ave() and the seq_along() functions.
I would like to add a column to a DF that contains the previous date that occurs in the rows that contains the same value in the column name.
I have a DF with the column name and date. I would like to add a column with the previous date recorder for that name. This is what I hope to get:
  name       date prev_date_name
1  aaa 2000-01-01           <NA>
2  aaa 2000-01-02     2000-01-01
3  bbb 2000-01-03           <NA>
4  bbb 2000-01-04     2000-01-03
5  bbb 2000-01-05     2000-01-04
6  bbb 2000-01-05     2000-01-05
7  eee 2000-01-06           <NA>
8  eee 2000-01-07     2000-01-06
9  eee 2000-01-08     2000-01-07

I am using this code:
#create DF
name <- c('aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'eee', 'eee', 'eee')
date <- c('2000-01-02', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07', '2000-01-08')
list_names <- data.frame(name, date)

#sort bij date
list_names <- arrange(list_names, date)

#add column with previous date from group with the same name
list_names$prev_date_name <- ave(list$date, list$name, FUN = function(x) ifelse(seq_along(x)==1, NA, x[as.integer(seq_along(x))-1]))

print(list_names)

But get this result:
  name       date prev_date_name
1  aaa 2000-01-01           <NA>
2  aaa 2000-01-02     2000-01-01
3  bbb 2000-01-03           <NA>
4  bbb 2000-01-04     2000-01-04
5  bbb 2000-01-05     2000-01-05
6  bbb 2000-01-05     2000-01-03
7  eee 2000-01-06           <NA>
8  eee 2000-01-07     2000-01-06
9  eee 2000-01-08     2000-01-06


The best way to achieve this (in my opinion) would be to simply use the dplyr library's mutate and lag functions:
library(dplyr)

list_names %>% 
  mutate(prev_date = lag(date), 
         .by = name)

However, if you must use ave() and seq_along(), using only base R you could do:
list_names$prev_date <- ave(as.Date(list_names$date), list_names$name, 
                            FUN = \(x) c(NA, x[seq_along(x) - 1]))

Both give:
#   name       date  prev_date
# 1  aaa 2000-01-01       <NA>
# 2  aaa 2000-01-02 2000-01-01
# 3  bbb 2000-01-03       <NA>
# 4  bbb 2000-01-04 2000-01-03
# 5  bbb 2000-01-05 2000-01-04
# 6  bbb 2000-01-05 2000-01-05
# 7  eee 2000-01-06       <NA>
# 8  eee 2000-01-07 2000-01-06
# 9  eee 2000-01-08 2000-01-07


There are a number of problems here:

code posted to SO should be complete. The code is using dplyr but the library statement is missing.

it would be better form not to mix base R and dplyr unnecessarily.

it is better to create a new data frame rather than clobber the input so that both exist at once making debugging easier.  It is not so bad in this case since you are simply inserting a new column but in general it is better to regard data as immutable.

use a pipeline if possible

list in the line before print should be list_name

seq_along is already integer and if we subtracted an integer 1, 1L there would be no point in as.integer.  Furthermore indexes don't have to be integer in the first place.

ifelse(seq_along(x)==1, NA, x[as.integer(seq_along(x))-1]) is incorrect. Both the true and false legs of the ifelse should be the same length but the false leg here is one shorter because as.integer(seq_along(x))-1] is 0, 1, 2, ...  and subscripting by 0 removes that element.

normally one uses \(x) rather than function(x) for anonymous functions to keep the code compact.

there are duplicate rows in the input data.  Is that intended?


Alternatives
1) To fix this with minimal changes and only base R try this:
o <- with(list_names, order(name, date))
list_names |>
  _[o, ] |>
  transform(prev_date_name = ave(date, name, 
   FUN = \(x) ifelse(seq_along(x) == 1, NA, x[c(NA, seq_along(x)[-length(x)])])))

2) however, this is shorter while still using only base R:
o <- with(list_names, order(name, date))
list_names |>
  _[o, ] |>
  transform(prev_date_name = ave(date, name, FUN = \(x) c(NA, head(x, -1))))

3) With dplyr then this which has partly been shown already in a comment and another answer.  Note that lag in dplyr conflicts with lag in base R and does not give the same answer so it is safest to preface it with dplyr:: to avoid confusion.
library(dplyr)

list_names %>%
  arrange(name, date) %>%
  mutate(prev_date_name = dplyr::lag(date), .by = name)

Note
Input from question:
name <- c('aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'eee', 'eee', 'eee')
date <- c('2000-01-02', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', 
  '2000-01-05', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07', '2000-01-08')
list_names <- data.frame(name, date)


If you are running a current R version, you can use sort_by. Your logic doesn't necesssary depend on seq_along, so in base R we could concisely do:
> list_names |> 
+   sort_by(~name + date) |> 
+   transform(prev_date=ave(date, name, FUN=\(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)])))
  name       date  prev_date
2  aaa 2000-01-01       <NA>
1  aaa 2000-01-02 2000-01-01
3  bbb 2000-01-03       <NA>
4  bbb 2000-01-04 2000-01-03
5  bbb 2000-01-05 2000-01-04
6  bbb 2000-01-05 2000-01-05
7  eee 2000-01-06       <NA>
8  eee 2000-01-07 2000-01-06
9  eee 2000-01-08 2000-01-07

Here's a bonus using data.table:
> library(data.table)
> dt <- as.data.table(list_names)
> 
> setorder(dt, name, date)
> dt[, prev_date := shift(date), by = name]
> dt
     name       date  prev_date
   <char>     <char>     <char>
1:    aaa 2000-01-01       <NA>
2:    aaa 2000-01-02 2000-01-01
3:    bbb 2000-01-03       <NA>
4:    bbb 2000-01-04 2000-01-03
5:    bbb 2000-01-05 2000-01-04
6:    bbb 2000-01-05 2000-01-05
7:    eee 2000-01-06       <NA>
8:    eee 2000-01-07 2000-01-06
9:    eee 2000-01-08 2000-01-07


Data
> dput(list_names)
structure(list(name = c("aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", 
"eee", "eee", "eee"), date = c("2000-01-02", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-03", 
"2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", 
"2000-01-08")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

Note, that dates should always be in the appropriate "Date" format. You should do:
list_names$date <- as.Date(list_names$date)

